# Uniformity of the difference between two random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

What can I say about the distribution of two random variables $A$ and $B$ such that $A-B$ is uniformly distributed?

Answer (score 1):

to have $A,B$ such that: $A-B \sim U$, both $A,B$ must be linearly trasformed samples of the same uniform distribution:
mini-proof: 
$$
\mbox{let: }u \sim U[0,1]\\
\begin{cases}
s_1\leftarrow u\cdot \lambda_1+\mu_1\\
s_2\leftarrow u\cdot \lambda_2+\mu_2
\end{cases} \implies 
\\ s_1-s_2=u\lambda_1+\mu_1-(u \lambda_2+\mu_2) 
= u(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)+(\mu_1-\mu_2) \implies \begin{cases}
c_1=\mu_1-\mu_2\\
c_2=\lambda_1-\lambda_2\\
s_1-s_2=u\cdot c_2 + c_1
\end{cases}
\implies s_1-s_2 \sim U[c_1,c_1+c_2] \\ 
\implies s_1-s_2 \in A-B \land \begin{cases}
s_1 \sim A=U[\mu_1,\mu_1+\lambda_1]\\
s_2 \sim B=U[\mu_2,\mu_2+\lambda_2]\\
\end{cases}
$$
but

Comment: What about $A$ and $B$ distributions?

Comment: now i made it a bit better, i tried to improve it...